# a recursive function that accepts two perimeters x and y. The function should return the value of x times y.i.e 2*4=4+4=

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int times(int x ,int y)
{
   if(x==0){
      return y;
   }
   else{
      cout<< y+(x-1,y);
   }
}

int main()
{
   int x,y;
   cout<<"enter x :";
   cin>>x;
   cout<<"enter y: ";
   cin>>y;
   cout<< times(x,y);
   cout<<endl;`enter code here`
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain more what you are trying to do?

Comment: You left out the recursive call. Also, the `0 * y == y` is questionable.

Comment: @JeffSloyer his homework ^^. Also, Danial, you aren't recursively calling your function. And you shouldn't have any `cout` in your `times(...)` function.

Comment: yesss,, it should be like  els{  return y+  (x-1,y);   }

Comment: it always return 8 ,,

Comment: @JeffSloyer                                                                                                    sorry im figuring out how to use this site ..the problem was that it is returning me 8 when i enter  3 and 4 respectively

Comment: @DanialKayani ` (x-1,y)` is not a function call. `4 + (3, 4)` is 8.

Answer (score 3):

```
int times(int x ,int y)
{
   if(x==0){
      return 0;
   }

   return (y + times(x-1,y)); // This is your recursive call.
}
```